# Touch based image processing in Objective-C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, image-processing, touch

OK I am building this app which does some user interactive image manipulations in iPhone/iPad.
This is basically a touch dependent function which re-shapes any image according to touch. A very similar thing can be found in the app Facetune.

My algorithm requires calculation of control points based on touch movements. Then based on these control points, I am generating a resultant grid which is used for interpolating the image. My entire approach is working all right. The only problem is it is slow for real-time. I am using

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

in the touches move function but it is still slow. Rescaling the image to about 360*something speeds up the process but at the cost of image quality.

My touch move code is :

```
- (void)updateImage
{
    int bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow([staticBG.image CGImage]);
    int height = CGImageGetHeight([staticBG.image CGImage]);
    int width = CGImageGetWidth([staticBG.image CGImage]);
    CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider([staticBG.image CGImage]));
    unsigned char *baseImage = (unsigned char *)CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);

    unsigned char *output_image;
    output_image = [self wrappingInterpolation :baseImage :orig :changed :width :height :bytesPerRow];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(output_image, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (context);
    UIImage *newimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CFRelease(imageRef);

    free(output_image);
    resultView.image = newimage;
    //staticBG.hidden = YES;
}
```

The method wrappingInterpolation does the actual image processing upon image pixels, that method is optimized highly to possibly run in real time. The orig and changed arguments are just two float*float matix which has the control points I need. I am seeing a constant overhead here which is getting the pixel data from UIImage everytime, then creating CGImageRef, CGCOntextRef, ColorSpaceRef etc.. then releasing it again. 
Anyway I could optimize these?
Suggest any other possible speed ups if possible. But I have really no idea about OpenGL or shaders so I might not not be able to do these through shaders.

Comment: (void)updateImage gets called inside touch-move

Comment: yes, wrap the image in 280*280 pixels or less. export the final control points to the larger image before saving. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the bottleneck resides in memory management.

When you extract raw bitmap data onto `CFDataRef pixelData`, you're unpacking the full image, and copying it completely. Then the interpolation routine creates again a copy of the data that is elaborated and stored into `output_image`.
Then you free memory twice, once for the old image you release by property assignment, once for the the `free(...)` command.

In terms of numbers: an iPhone 5 takes photos at 3264x2448, this means 22MB in RGB format (8b per channel), doubled by the wrapping routine. And this double allocation and double copy (as well as a double freeing) occurs at the rate at which the events are fired. You must add also the time that you routine uses for processing the input data: looping on every pixels means 8 millions of iterations in a 8MP image. This requires definitely *a lot* of computation power.

Note that what you want to achieve is somehow similar to real time video/image processing; as for video processing, you should adopt specific techniques. OpenGL would be really your best option, but requires more efforts. Some basic suggestions might be

- **Avoid allocating twice**: as you're already copying the data, work directly on `baseImage`, if your algorithm allows in-place transformations.
- **Cache image data**: don't extract bitmap data every time. If your algorithm works "additively", keep the same `CFDataRef` and work on it every time.

  In your routine you use always `staticBG` as input data: this suggest the algorithm always changes the base image. You can cache the raw image data once for all.
- **Avoid wrapping in `UIImage`**: `CALayer` has a useful property `contents` that might be set to a `CGImageRef` to display the content. Also, what you're doing is somehow related to animation so you really could drop the *UI* stuff and work on a *CA* level, that is more flexible (and fast). See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/contents).
- If you really must use an intermediate memory storage, **reuse the same memory** and copy onto it: the size of the image won't probably change, and you save at least the allocation time.
- **Prerender the final result**: you can actually just work at the size of the screen, and store the information you need to elaborate the full size image. Then you do it in a subsequent phase.

These suggestions can avoid all the unnecessary allocations, what is left is only a copy operation, if your algorithm is not additive or cannot be run in place. Some suggestions (that you might have already implemented) for your algorithm:

- Process data inplace if possible.
- Loop only on the pixels that are actually going to be modified.
- Copy only the data you need to work on.
- Treat pixels as vectors and use optimized functions, if you can. Take a look at the [Accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html). There are many routines for working direct on images.
- Use [Quartz 2D](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html) where you can.

---

Still, the best suggestion is: **switch to OpenGL**. Even in the best scenario, you have a problem: the call to `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`, that you cannot avoid. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGBitmapContextCreateImage) says that your data is copied by CoreGraphics: this means that every frame requires at least one full copy of the data. As far as I know, you cannot modify in real time the buffer that is being displayed. The best approximation is given by OpenGL, that runs almost at hardware level, and writes into a buffer that is flushed straight into a `EAGLContext` displayed by CoreAnimation.

This is a very different approach, but is extremely fast. Some visual effects (like Gaussian blur) require quite a lot of power, but run real time under OpenGL. You can start looking at this [GLImageProcessing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html), it's a very interesting example of raster image manipulation. Moreover, OpenGL is very well equipped for image warping too: you can display an image as texture on a plane mesh and then deform it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I will be looking into the GLImageProcessing tutorial shortly, till then I am implementing the improvements you mentioned. On a side note I checked out how Facetune was doing it and YES they use their own customized OpenGLES engine.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes GL is a good strategy. Don't let yourself be fooled by the amount of management code used in the example: this is OpenGLES 1.1, now there's GLKit and ES2.0 with shaders that do most of the job for you. All the interesting stuff is in `Imaging.c`, basically splitting the vfx into very simple additive operations on pixels, realised by rendering a textured plane with the proper blend function.